# I need a mechanism/method to control a shaft that can rotate at different speeds. (faster clockwise and slower anti-clockwise)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanical

[image]I need to develop a mechanism - Where in I have a shaft that needs to rotate at different speeds. Lets say at a higher RPM clockwise and a lower RPM anti-clockwise. 
This shaft is attached to my machine, so I can't have 2 shafts. 
If i have 2 motors to the same shaft, I'm afraid there'll be feedback on the other motor, while one is running.

For example, like the image attached. Both the motors are connected to the lead screw. The motor (and the lead screw attached to it) on the left rotates at a higher rpm and this motion is used to lift my system. Similarly from the other side but to drop it quicker (the reason for the speed difference).

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: You could use one motor and just add different size pulley for each speed. Or you could use a servo / stepper motor with a notch type belt and notch type pulley, so that you can control exactly how far up and down each move. Also with the servo /  stepper you can have variable speeds. Plus with a servo/stepper you can use a computer to control this and possibly set up a PLC(Programmable Logic Controller) to automate the process.

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. If both motors are direct drive, and with an appropriate electronics you should be able to back drive whichever motor is not running. If either has a gearbox you will need a clutch. If each motor will only ever turn in one direction then this could be a simple freewheel clutch for each motor.